# Initramfs: ERROR: Bad version passed vmlinuz-5.15.36

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I trying to build the kernel 5.15.36. My standard kernel - 5.17.5. During initramfs I get error: Bad version passed vmlinuz-5.15.36

System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

What to do?

Comment: "*During initramfs ...*" -- Initramfs is not an activity or operation, so this phrase makes no sense.  It also has no context; what is the boot log prior to and after this error message?  You need to provide a lot more details:  How did you build the (cpio) archive? How are you providing the (cpio) archive?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 20 to 22 this is what I have did:
booting OS from the One to last kernel and running commands below in order:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k {the last version of kernel eg: 5.15.0-27-generic}

sudo update-grub
```